# @mixin select a specific placeholder by using argument

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to use a mixin with an argument and inside a placeholder.
The idea is to use one line of code to select a specific placeholder in a class.
Actually, I don't know if there is another better way to do that, maybe with a function or other.
I'm learning Sass, so I'm trying to experiment.

HTML

```
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
// VAR
$size-xs: 30px;
$size-s: 50px;
$size-m: 70px;

$color-1: orange;
$color-2: rgb(34,139,86);

@mixin box($val) {
  %box-one {
    width: $size-s;
    height: $size-s;
    background: $color-1;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 6px;
  }
  %box-two {
    width: $size-s;
    height: $size-s;
    background: $color-2;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 6px;
  }
  .box {
    @extend #{$val} !optional;
  }
}

.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  @include box(box-one);
}
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your code is not working because your forgot to put a `%` before `#{$val}`:

```
.box {
  @extend %#{$val} !optional;
}
```

Anyhow, it's not a good idea to put placeholder selectors inside a mixin because every time the mixin is called, you are creating new selectors. It means that for example if you add:

```
.randomSelector {
  @include box(box-one);
}
```

You will get:

```
.wrap .box { ... }
.randomSelector .box { ... }
```

Instead of:

```
.randomSelector .box, .wrap .box { ... }
```

So I would recommend you to externalize `%box-one` and `%box-two`.

One last thing, if the only difference between these two classes is the `background` property, maybe using a single class regrouping the commons properties would be a better optimization:

```
.box {
  width: $size-s;
  height: $size-s;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

%box-one {
  background: $color-1;
}

%box-two {
  background: $color-2;
}

@mixin box($val) {
  .box {
    @extend %box-#{$val} !optional;
  }
}

.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  @include box(one);
}
```

If you have more box styles you can even dynamically create the placeholders:

```
$boxStyles: (
  one: $color-1,
  two: $color-2
);

@each $box, $style in $boxStyles {
  %box-#{$box}  {
    background: $style;
  }
}
```